# Gizmos from Editor Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to display gizmos from an `Editor` script instead of a `MonoBehaviour` script?

I like the look of this Handle:

```
Handles.color = Color.red;
Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
```

The problem is that it is selectable, and I don't want it to be selectable. So is there a way for me to draw something like that? I also don't want to use Gizmos, because they run in `MonoBehaviour` and not `Editor`.

Answer (score 1):

Handles can't be unselectable and Gizmo always need to derive from Monobehavior.
But there is a function called **DrawGizmo**.

https://docs.unity3d.com/351/Documentation/ScriptReference/DrawGizmo.DrawGizmo.html

Actually it's not inherited by Editor or MonoBehaviour so you can use it for your script.

There is also a way in the Enum for deactivate the *Pickable Mode*.

https://docs.unity3d.com/351/Documentation/ScriptReference/GizmoType.html

Hope it will helps you !

Comment: If I understood the question properly this is the way to go!

Comment: It doesn't seem that I can draw a gizmo at a unknown offset, because I would like to draw the gizmo at at the location where a mesh vertex is located...